unexpected greed before an optional regex group
This is a follow-on to this answered question.
For the input string
kau(77)n6b(88)av7(99)x

why does
.*?(a|b)?.*?\((\d+)\)

not capture the a in kau nor the b in n6b (as shown here), while
[^ab(]*(a|b)?.*?\((\d+)\)

is able to successfully capture both the a and b (as shown here)?
In other words,
.*?(a|b)?.*?\((\d+)\)
 ^^
  if this is not greedy

kau(77)n6b(88)av7(99)x
 ^
 then why does it eat this "a" rather than capture it

[^ab(]*(a|b)?.*?\((\d+)\)
  ^
  which forces me to instead use "don't eat the a"

I have also excluded ( from the characters so that I can match the numbers later in the string, but the idea is the same in that case, too, I think. That is, if I have called out an explicit a or ( to come after a non-greedy operation, why does the greedy-ness consume it anyway?
This is a request for an explanation, since I've already got the syntax, I simply don't understand it.
Some more examples:
doesn't work with non-greedy: link
works with excluded characters: link

Wherever you use ? in the end it makes that pattern non-greedy hence it matches as little as possible. You will get into same problem if you make other working regex non-greedy like this: [^ab(]?(a|b)?(.?)((\d+))`

Yes, that is my question. Why isn't "as little as possible" only the k in kau? Why does it think that the least-greedy thing to do is to move through the a rather than stop and capture it?

Like both re.findall( r".*?(a)", "kau" ) and re.findall( r".*(a)", "kau" ) successfully capture the a. What about this larger context invalidates that?

As you are using ? in (a|b)? also it ends up matching nothing

That ? means {0,1} since the a may not appear. I've added some longer regex101 examples to the main question that show a match to a number in the absence of an a.

You need (?:.*?(a|b))?. It is just how optional patterns work when put in sequence.

That works! Thanks. I guess "it just does" is something that I have learned now. Thanks.

The point is that .*?(a|b)?.*?\( works like this: the first .*? is skipped (as it is "lazy"), (a|b)? matches an empty space since it does not have to consume a character (it is optional and k is not a nor b), then .*? is skipped, then ( must follow. And the second .*? is expanded until ( and the rest of the pattern is found (you can check it by using .*?(a|b)?(.*?)\((\d+)\)).

I think this answer can help a lot, too.

Nice! This makes sense. FWIW, this explanation here is clearer to me than your link from seven years ago, but thanks for digging that up, too. I think that for me, the punch line is that .*? doesn't get expanded until the very end in order to cover any non-obligatory parts. As can be seen in the preceding question that spawned this one, I can capture the optional a if it is at the beginning of the string, since in that case I don't encounter your excellent explanation of "k is not a or b". Awesome. Thanks.

Oh, yes, the 2016 explanation is awesome. I see that we are using here some "tempered greed" rather than the suggested "unrolled loop." Understanding this as a loop through an order of operations is the explanation that I needed. Dziękuję!
